# ImageMagick offset text from centre

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to include a conditional offset to the gravity centre of my text on my generated image. I've done some reading and apparently I can use

Here is the code:

```
<?php

function process($inputdata)
{
$width = 400;
$height = 300;

$textBackground = new ImagickPixel('transparent');
$textColor = new ImagickPixel('#FFF');

$gradient = new Imagick();
//gradient:angle=angle in degrees
$gradient->newPseudoImage($width, $height, 'gradient:#3a7bd5-#3a6073');

$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage($width, $height, $textBackground);

$gradient->setImageColorspace($image->getImageColorspace());

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor($textColor);
$draw->setFontSize( 25 );
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );
//$draw->setGeometry(Imagick::Geometry +20 +20); --New code that doesn't work

$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $inputdata); 

$gradient->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$gradient->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $gradient;
return;
}
?>
```

This is the code I tried to use:

```
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );
$draw->setGeometry(Imagick::Geometry +20 +20);
```

Which in theory should offset the text from the gravity center, however when I try it it stops my image generating. I think I have made a mistake because the only example code I can find is for the command line, not for the PHP interface.

Comment: Comment out the header line that sets the content type, enable proper PHP error reporting, and look at what error messages or warnings you get in the script output.

Comment: @CBroe I did that I still get no errors, just the image didn't work. I put this in my PHP file ```error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL); ```

Comment: According to the php Imagick page setGeometry is not an option. You can probably offset the text on the annotateImage line.

Comment: _"just the image didn't work"_ - are you looking at the actual script output as I asked you to - or are you just looking at a "broken image" symbol in the browser going "du'h?"

Comment: @Bonzo This is the command line version I found in the docs http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#geometry

Comment: @Cbroe I just added the debug code I found off google to my function php script (and the php page calling it) and loaded it on my hosting via URL - I don't really know what you are asking me to do

Comment: _"and loaded it on my hosting from my URL"_ - and that means what exactly? Did you just input the URL to this script, that outputs the image data and nothing else, into the browser address bar? Did you comment out the content-type header?

Comment: The command line you are looking at is for Imagemagick directly. You are using an Imagemapick API called Imagick. It causes quite a bit of confusion. Basically the API is like a class written by a third party and does not contain all the options of the full Imagemagick program.

Comment: @Cbroe I means I loaded it from a URL with the file sat on my hosting, I don't know how else I can say it to you really. I did comment out the content type as you asked.

Comment: Can you give us that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to -geometry. You use the offsets in compositeImage to shift the image. But you need to set the gravity first.